# Автозаполнение в контактной форме

Tags: wordpress

Нужно в контактной форме сделать автозаполнение услуги. 
[image: заголовок который должен автозаполняться в поле формы]

```
<div class="tg-widgetcontent">
            <form class="tg-themeform tg-dashboardform">
                <fieldset>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" value="<?php echo esc_attr($service); ?>">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="<?php esc_html_e('Your Name', 'listingo'); ?>">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="<?php esc_html_e('Email Address', 'listingo'); ?>">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone" placeholder="<?php esc_html_e('Phone', 'listingo'); ?>">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <textarea class="form-control" name="description" placeholder="<?php esc_html_e('Message', 'listingo'); ?>"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="email_to" value="<?php echo esc_attr($author_profile->user_email); ?>" class="form-control">
                    <?php wp_nonce_field('sp_dashboard_contact_form', 'security'); ?>
                    <button class="tg-btn tg-btn-lg tg-dashboard-form-btn" type="button"><?php esc_html_e('Записаться', 'listingo'); ?></button>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Форма находится вот здесь: https://photiko.ru/professional/deniska/

Comment: А в чём проблема?

Comment: Первая форма не заполняется текст услуги Тестовая

Comment: А где код, которым вы заполняете услугу?

Comment: нужно как-то тайтл забирать с названия услуги $title = !empty($service['title']) ? $service['title'] : '';

Comment: Нужно не "как-то забирать тайтл" (и непонятно куда вставлять), а использовать плагины для форм. Напр CF7.

Answer (score 0):

Действительно, лучше всего использовать плагин Contact Form 7. Как вариант, вы сможете сделать форму для регистрации одной или множества услуг.

Например, у вас одна услуга "Свадебная фотография". Вы можете назвать форму ее именем и автоматически выводить ее в текстовом поле, уже не требующим заполнения пользователем.

Одна услуга:

```
[text* text-516 default:title="Свадебная фотография"]
```

Множество услуг:

```
[select* menu-394 include_blank "Услуга 1" "Услуга 2" "Услуга 3"]
```

Если пользователь не зарегистрирован на сайте, далее выводите остальные поля:

```
[text* your-name placeholder "Ваше имя"]
[email* your-email placeholder "Ваш email"]
[tel* tel-354 placeholder "Ваш телефон"]

[textarea your-message placeholder "Ваше сообщение"]
[submit "Отправить"]
```

Если пользователь зарегистрирован на сайте, поля будут другими. Это работает только если пользователь заполнил свой профиль.

```
[text* your-name default:user_first_name]
[text* your-name default:user_last_name]
[email* your-email default:user_email]
[tel* tel-354 default:user_phone]

[textarea your-message placeholder "Ваше сообщение"]
[submit "Отправить"]
```

Если прочитать документацию, вы сможете сделать гораздо больше.

Comment: Дело в том, что фотографы создают сами названия своих услуг, оттуда я хотел автозаполнение их. А данный множественный пример [select* menu-394 include_blank "Услуга 1" "Услуга 2" "Услуга 3"] не подойдет.